# Is there a resource with latex snippets?

Tags: examples, learning, resources

I have been working in Latex for a little over a month now and I have been searching for a resource (like a website) to find latex snippets for commonly used structures or equations.

For example, a block diagram of a PID controller, often used equations like the equations of motions etc.

Does anyone know if this kind of resource exists?

Comment: I think it's called tex.stackexchange.com `;^)`  Hint: use the "search" feature.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: For graphics, you have [texample.net](http://texample.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing diagrams of all sorts I'm a fan of [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net), in which you can write programs to draw figures (and moving, rotating, and otherwise spindling and mangling the result is easy, so repetitive structures are a snap). Check it's gallery (at the linked page). It brings an enormous variety of libraries, from 2D and 3D plots (and primitives to build your own) to drawing trees, fancy arrowheads, and so on.

Yes, there are native LaTeX ways to do all this, but the language doesn't fit very well, and (sadly) much of TikZ blows up when used with babel (at least Spanish), so that's out of the question for me.

Another alternative that I became aware of recently is [ipe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net), this one is geared towards interactive (drawing with the mouse, essentially) use. Haven't tried it in anger, besides my drawing skills being a constant source of bad jokes from my students I guess that won't work so well.

For drawing graphs I find [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) useful. You can give LaTeX fonts for labels, but sadly not much else.

Both of asymptote and ipe are well integrated, in that you can specify LaTeX fonts and colors, and even label stuff with equations.

Answer (score 1):

- For TikZ examples such as diagrams: http://www.texample.net/
- For examples and help with equation writing: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have you seen http://www.latextemplates.com/? (No affiliation)

Comment: While this is certainly true, in general, there's no way to provide "essential parts" of the answer. The link is the answer, and the site provides exactly what the name suggests, i.e. LaTeX Templates.

Comment: I would rather take it as a comment ;-) For sure, the question is too broad to be answered